# How to combine where and groupBy in Spark's DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I use aggregate functions in a `where` clause in Apache Spark 1.6?

Consider the following DataFrame

```
+---+------+
| id|letter|
+---+------+
|  1|     a|
|  2|     b|
|  3|     b|
+---+------+
```

How can I select all rows where `letter` occurs more than once, i.e. the expected output would be

```
+---+------+
| id|letter|
+---+------+
|  2|     b|
|  3|     b|
+---+------+
```

This does obviously not work:

```
df.where(
  df.groupBy($"letter").count()>1
)
```

My example its about `count`, but I'd like to be able to use other aggregate functions (the results thereof) as well.

EDIT:

Just for counting,I just came up with the following solution:

```
df.groupBy($"letter").agg(
  collect_list($"id").as("ids")
 )
.where(size($"ids") > 1)
.withColumn("id", explode($"ids"))
.drop($"ids")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use left semi join:

```
df.join(
  broadcast(df.groupBy($"letter").count.where($"count" > 1)),
  Seq("letter"),
  "leftsemi"
)
```

or window functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df
  .withColumn("count", count($"*").over(Window.partitionBy("letter")))
  .where($"count" > 1)
```

In Spark 2.0 or later you can Bloom filter but it is not available in 1.x